# Laravel Doesn't see Routes in Scaffolded Auth login

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

**Code**:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
    <a href="{{ route('password.request') }}">forgot?</a>
</div>
```

**Error**:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'password' (T_STRING), expecting
>   ',' or ')' (View:
>   /path/to/laravel/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php)

When I'm trying to vardump route('password.request') in Tinker it's OK, but Tinker uses PHP 7.1.19 and the web interface 7.1.11 (if that is important).

**Stack trace**:

```
  1. {main}() /home/app/path/public/index.php:0
  2. Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError-&gt;() /home/vagrant/www/tonezone/storage/framework/views/e994cd5027a170d4c5b3b3e08ce6dd81af433087.php:39
  3. {main}() /home/app/path/public/index.php:0
```

**Line 39**:

```
<a href="<?php echo e(route('password.request')); ?>"><?php echo app('translator')->getFromJson('forgot?'); ?></a>
```

Comment: can you paste the complete stack trace

Comment: What version of laravel is this?  If it is >=  5.X, try {!! route('password.request') !!}

Comment: Have you messed around with core code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'password.request' was a string it wouldn't give an error, so I think your quotation marks are inverted.

I would guess that you probably missed one quotation mark in the previous statement in braces. Maybe you were adding translations? It's easy to miss something like it.

Comment: yup, forgot to close one string in previous braces. It was translations exactly